# flask testing can't set flask.g by appcontext_pushed.connected_to

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pytest

My code is wrong.. So the question is over.Thanks tmt so much.

=================== origin question ⬇️ =================

I try to test my flask app(python3.8.1) follow flask-doc

[flask-doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/)

I want to set flask.g for my app before request in testing, so I use **appcontext_pushed.connected_to** func, but it not work...

I build a small demo down here. You can have a try by copy it in demo.py

> pip install flask, binker, pytest
>
> pytest demo.py

You will get a AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'name'.......

Why...

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from flask import appcontext_pushed, g, json, jsonify, Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


def fetch_current_user_from_database():
    return {'name': 'aa'}


def get_user():
    user = getattr(g, 'user', None)
    if user is None:
        user = fetch_current_user_from_database()
        g.name = user['name']
    return user


@app.route('/users/me')
def users_me():
    return jsonify(username=g.name)


@contextmanager
def user_set(app, user):
    def handler(sender, **kwargs):
        g.user = user
    with appcontext_pushed.connected_to(handler, app):
        yield


def test_1():
    username = '123'
    with user_set(app, username):
        with app.test_client() as c:
            resp = c.get('/users/me')
            data = json.loads(resp.data)
            assert data['username'] == username
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overridden some parts of the example from the documentation and therefore `g.name` doesn't exist when `users_me()` is called. `fetch_current_user_from_database()` and `get_user()` seems to me irrelevant in your example. You are not testing them and they never get called. The only thing that your test seems to test is that `users_me()` returns the user's name.

Therefore, in the test you should set the entire user object. What such object would be depends on your application because this is not Flask-specific. Given that you have not provided such information let's just use a mock object:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

from contextlib import contextmanager
from flask import appcontext_pushed, g, json, jsonify, Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/users/me')
def users_me():
    return jsonify(username=g.user.name)


@contextmanager
def user_set(app, user):
    def handler(sender, **kwargs):
        g.user = user

    with appcontext_pushed.connected_to(handler, app):
        yield

def test_1():
    user = MagicMock()
    user.name = 'aa'

    with user_set(app, user):
        with app.test_client() as c:
            resp = c.get('/users/me')
            data = json.loads(resp.data)
            assert data['username'] == user.name
```

Comment: thank you so much for encourage me. The problem is over

Answer (score 0):

The right code is：

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from flask import appcontext_pushed, g, json, jsonify, Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/users/me')
def users_me():
    return jsonify(username=g.user)


@contextmanager
def user_set(app, user):
    def handler(sender, **kwargs):
        g.user = user
    with appcontext_pushed.connected_to(handler, app):
        yield


def test_1():
    user = '123'
    with user_set(app, user):
        with app.test_client() as c:
            resp = c.get('/users/me')
            data = json.loads(resp.data)
            assert data['username'] == user
```

It's a demo like i said. In my real app, I want to send a user object to g which created by the function below.

```
def login(client, email, password):
    print(f'login_info test start')
    ret = client.post('/api/login', json=dict(
        email=email,
        password=password
    ), follow_redirects=True)
    assert ret.status_code == 200
    data = json.loads(ret.data)
    uid = data['uid']
    customer = CustomerService.get(uid)
    print(f'login test end {customer.email}')
    assert customer
```

you may notice that there is no return in the function. So I get a None and send it to g. BUT I DIDN'T NOTICE IT THAT NIGHT.

flask-doc has some incomplete and ambiguous demo:

```py
with user_set(app, my_user):
    with app.test_client() as c:
        resp = c.get('/users/me')
        data = json.loads(resp.data)
        self.assert_equal(data['username'], my_user.username)
```

if app is change to flaskr, I may have more courage to try.

```py
with user_set(flaskr, my_user):
    with app.test_client() as c:
        resp = c.get('/users/me')
        data = json.loads(resp.data)
        self.assert_equal(data['username'], my_user.username)
```

I search on google about 5hours to find out why appcontext_pushed.connected_to send nothing...Every demo I get is not working. I've run out of my courage.

thanks tmt answer such a easy question. You show me it really working, there's something wrong in my own code. You give me courage which really means a lot. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You're not the only one to encounter this weird behaviour! Having come across this recently I had thought OK cool, plenty of tests could benefit from this.

Your code isn't actually wrong from what I can see (at least not the parts under the lens). I got this working using app_context() instead of test_client()

Maybe there has been some changes that messed up some backwards compatibility. Bit frustrating for sure. The clue was in the @contextmanager decorated func: appcontext_pushed

But seems test_client() doesn't push an appcontext

Here is what worked for me:

```py
@contextmanager
def user_set(state, _user):
    def handler(sender, **kwargs):
        g.user = _user

    with appcontext_pushed.connected_to(handler, state):
        yield

with user_set(self.application, user):
    # use app_context() instead of test_client() context manager
    with app.app_context():
        client = app.test_client()
        # then make your request
        ...
```

The docs are indeed a little misleading here

Edit: Don't run out of courage :)